# autoComplete - action & onClick

Tags: jsf, primefaces, autocomplete, onclick

I have below code, There can be a case when user types something there is no auto suggestion available, but still i want the text entered by the user.
My `onClick` function does gets called, but i want to get the value the user has types.

I have tried below approaches, but none seems to be working.

**AutoComplete tag**

```
<p:autoComplete id="cityInput"
                value="#{myBean.text}"
                style="margin-right:15px;"
                completeMethod="#{myBean.fetchData}"
                global="false"
                forceSelection="true"
                maxResults="5">
</p:autoComplete>
```

**Button**

```
<p:commandButton id="searchCity"
                 value="Search"
                 icon="ui-icon-search"
                 onclick="captureSearchText();"
                 action="#{myBean.search}"/>
```

**Script**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   function captureSearchText(){
        alert("88");
        //var searchVal = myAutoComplete.input.val();
        //var searchVal = document.getElementById("cityInput");
        //alert(searchVal.value);
        //return true;
    }
</script>
```

**Edit Section**

When I press `ENTER` key, I get the searched string in my `fetchData`, maybe because it is `p:commandButton`. But on **click of button** also I want to get the searched text. I hope it is clear now. What can I do to get search text on mouse click of search button. tried invoking JavaScript function.

Comment: Why not just have the completeMethod return what the user typed?

Comment: @Kukeltje Pls let me know how exactly will it work, if possible to post it as a answer with syntax, i have just started on this, so not much idea.

Comment: Uhhmmm this is just adding the search parameter to the results if they are empty. Nothing special. No need for the whole capture thing…  And it is difficult for me to create code answers from my mobile phone.

Comment: @Kukeltje i think i did put up my question correctly. Pls see the edit.

Comment: Your question states that you still want the query string if there is no result. So you ALWAYS want the queryString, even if there is a result? Well, then there is still no need to to do this complex stuff.. Just save the queryString on the server in a viewScoped bean (and then you can even choose to do this when the result is empty or always). Or do I still fail to understand the problem?

Comment: @Kukeltje yes my bean is in `view` scope only, but somehow i am not able to get the value on `mouseclick`, if possible can you please edit the answer if required, or i will try with your answer if you think it is still applicable and revert. Thanks for the support you are giving. :)

Comment: Little enhancement in the answer, but pay attention the javascript is not needed anymore

Comment: @Kukeltje yes it worked, thanks, But seems like a temp fix, like returning what user types, showing in option, forcing him to select and then getting back searched text in server side.

Comment: He does not need to select… it is your choice if you want it to behave that way or not. You can also leave the returning of the value out. Your choice

Comment: @Kukeltje how can i do, is it `forceSelection="true"` decides, please explain.

Comment: Do what? Force selection yes. That is the way, but you wrote you did not want that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the completeMethod `#{myBean.fetchData}` just return the search string as entered by the user if the real 'searching' does not yield any results.

```
public List<String> fetchData(String query) {
    List<String> results = searchService.search(query);
    if (results.isEmpty() {
        results.add(query);
    }
    return results;
}
```

There is in fact nothing 'jsf' to this, plain java creativity.

But the user still has to select it then unless the autocomplete has an autoselect option. Not sure about this. But you can also store the query string in a variable server side and use that if the user does not select anything (setting the field to required is better then imo)

```
public List<String> fetchData(String query) {
    List<String> results = searchService.search(query);
    this.queryString = "";
    if (results.isEmpty() {
        results.add(query);
        this.queryString = query
    }
    return results;
}
```

Or move it outside the ifEmpty if you always want to store it

Answer (score 0):

`forceSelection="true"` was an issue actually, it was forcing a selection.
I have removed it and it ran smoothly.

Answer by @Kukeltje is also good, but that is something a workaround, and `forceSelection="true"` was actually the root cause.